# Can Vertica call a http get function?

Tags: vertica

> Can Vertica call http get function?
>
> IF yes, how?

I have a link i need to access from Vertica.

Comment: I know there is a vget Java class in Vertica ! But i don't think is what you need !

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Vertica may be able to use cURL to open and read a file over HTTP using a subclass of [UDSource](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#18050.htm) (C++):

> The UDSource class is responsible for acquiring the data from an external source and producing that data in a streaming manner. A wrapper is also provided for UDSource called ContinuousUDSource. ContinuousUDSource provides an abstraction that allows you to treat the input data as a continuous stream of data. This allows you to write the data from the source "at will" instead of having to create an iterator to use the base UDSource method.

**Example UDSource**

> ```
> class CurlSource : public UDSource {
> private:
>     URL_FILE *handle;
>     std::string url;
>
>     virtual StreamState process(ServerInterface &srvInterface, DataBuffer &output) {
>         output.offset = url_fread(output.buf, 1, output.size, handle);
>         return url_feof(handle) ? DONE : OUTPUT_NEEDED;
>     }
> public:
>     CurlSource(std::string url) : url(url) {}
>
>    void setup(ServerInterface &srvInterface) {
>         handle = url_fopen(url.c_str(),"r");
>     }
>
>    void destroy(ServerInterface &srvInterface) {
>         url_fclose(handle);
>     }
> };
> ```

Additionally, it appears that you can use the [standard HDFS connector](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#18542.htm):

```
COPY testTable SOURCE Hdfs(url='http://hadoop:50070/webhdfs/v1/tmp/test.txt', username='hadoopUser');
```